# The problem of not being able to change the background color, thickness and position of the texts in the Streamlit Multiple Page App's Side Bar

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, streamlit

Streamlit Version: 1.13.0

in Homepage.py:

```
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(
        page_title= "Multipage App",
        page_icon="")


st.title("Main Page")

st.markdown('<style>div[class="css-6qob1r e1fqkh3o3"] {color:black; font-weight: 900; background: url("https://media2.giphy.com/media/46hpy8xB3MiHfruixn/giphy.gif");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:350%;} </style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)


st.markdown('<style>div[class="css-y3drt2 e1fqkh3o5"] {color:red; } </style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)#NOT WORKING-------------------------------------------
```

[image]

I want to change the color, font, and position of the Homepage, Application, and Contact texts. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay close attention to the classes to get the right class and also making sure you wrap the `css` in a valid format in order to get it working.
This is a work around which I think should solve your problem. But I am not really sure if there are change in class names in deferent versions of streamlit.

```py
st.markdown("""
  <style>
      ul[class="css-wjbhl0 e1fqkh3o9"]{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 2rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .css-17lntkn {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: yellow;
      }
      
      .css-pkbazv {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
  </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Which streamlit Version is it? İf it is not v1.13, css class may be changed. I tried the above code but it is not working.

Comment: This works for `version 1.15.2`.

Comment: I couldn't adjust the space between emoji and text, it doesn't move emojis either (ul section)

Comment: I posted a straight forward question with a follow up answer on that subject which I think might be beneficial to someone else who happened to have a hard time getting the proper classes. You can refer to [streamlit multipage names edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694133/how-to-give-some-gap-between-emojis-and-page-names-in-a-streamlit-multiple-pages/74694163#74694163)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this [via inline CSS and st.markdown](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/css-hacks/14501), although it's admittedly hacky.

```
def _set_block_container_style(
    max_width: int = 1200,
    max_width_100_percent: bool = False,
    padding_top: int = 1,
    padding_right: int = 1,
    padding_left: int = 1,
    padding_bottom: int = 1,
):

if max_width_100_percent:
    max_width_str = f"max-width: 100%;"
else:
    max_width_str = f"max-width: {max_width}px;"
    
styl = f"""
    <style>
        .reportview-container .main .block-container{{
            {max_width_str}
            padding-top: {padding_top}rem;
            padding-right: {padding_right}rem;
            padding-left: {padding_left}rem;
            padding-bottom: {padding_bottom}rem;
        }}
        }}
    </style>
```