# How to give some gap between emojis and page names in a streamlit multiple pages app

Tags: css, streamlit

I have a streamlit multipage app whereby the pages have emojis attached to the page names and want to add some space or gap between the emojis and the page names. Is there any work around to achieve that? I tried some `css` approaches but it just never worked.

Illustration image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this up to see if it works for you. **Note:** The classes might defer due to change of streamlit versions. But this should work on `version 1.15.2`.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.markdown("""
    <style>
    .css-8hkptd {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```